# How to make WinScp use the same proxy as Cygwin ssh

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, cygwin, winscp

I'm working on a Windows machine behind a firewall.

In Windows control panel, there's a proxy .pac file configured, which browsers use successfully.

When I use ssh (within Cygwin), I have a `ProxyCommand` configured to reach outside hosts, through some host (say some.where.com port 80), and that works.

My problem is with WinScp. If I don't make any special proxy settings, it won't connect; but if I set the same proxy server and port as I have configured for ssh in Cygwin - it won't connect (and doesn't tell me why exactly).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

If your proxying setup under cygwin uses a certain command - specifically, `connect-proxy`, use that.

For example, suppose your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file has the following line for your target machine:

```
MyDestinationMachine
    ProxyCommand connect-proxy -H some.where.com:80 %h %p
```

In this case, in WinScp, go to <kbd>Preferences</kbd> | <kbd>Connection</kbd> | <kbd>Proxy</kbd> , and within that pane - *don't* set a proxy server. Instead set a **local** proxy type.

Then down in <kbd>Proxy Settings</kbd>, Browse for the path of your proxy command; then add the relevant parameters. For the example above, this could be:

```
C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\connect-proxy.exe  -H some.where.com:80 %host %port
```

Now, if ssh in Cygwin works, then so should WinScp.